# Join TSQL Tables in same DB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to do a simple join of two tables in the same DB.

The expected result is:
To get all Node_ID's From the Table T_Tree that are the same as the TREE_CATEGORY from the Table T_Documents

My T_Documents Tabel:

```
+--------+----------------+---------------------+
| Doc_ID | TREEE_CATEGORY |        Desc         |
+--------+----------------+---------------------+
|  89893 |           1363 | Test                |
|  89894 |          1364  | with a tab or 4 spa |
+--------+----------------+---------------------+
```

T_Tree Tabel

```
+----------+-------+
| Node_ID  | Name  |
+----------+-------+
|    89893 | Hallo |
|   89894  |   BB  |
+----------+-------+
```

Doc_ID is the primary key in the T_Documents Table and Tree_Category is the Foreign key

Node_ID is the primary key in the T_Tree Tabel

```
SELECT DBName.dbo.T_Tree.NODE_ID
FROM DBName.dbo.T_Documents
 inner join TREE_CATEGORY on T_Documents.TREE_CATEGORY = DBName.dbo.T_Tree.NODE_ID
```

I can not figure it out how to do it correctly .. is this even the right approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  Try this:

```
SELECT t2.NODE_ID
FROM DBName.dbo.T_Documents t1
INNER JOIN DBName.dbo.T_Tree t2
    ON t1.Doc_ID = t2.NODE_ID
```

Comments:

- I used *aliases* in the query, which are a sort of shorthand for the table names.  Aliases can make a query easier to read because it removes the need to always list full table names.
- You need to specify table names in the `JOIN` clause, and the columns used for joining in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks allot for you answer Tim :)

Answer (score 0):

Your **SQL** should be:

```
SELECT DBName.dbo.T_Tree.NODE_ID
  FROM DBName.dbo.T_Documents d
 inner join T_Tree t on d.Doc_ID = t.Node_ID
```

Remember: you join **relations** (tables), not fields.

Also, for it to work, you need to have common values on `Node_ID` and `Doc_ID` fields. That is, for each value in `Doc_ID` of `T_Documents` table there must be an equal value in `Node_ID` field of `T_Tree` table.